# onProgressUpdate() for AsyncTask class doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to show progressbar where image downloaded and set custom color 
I do it in onProgressUpdate() but it dosent work it also doesn't appear in logcat.. it also shows a white screen until download completed and if I press back button during the download, it will crash.

my code:

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String ,Void, Bitmap> {

    Bitmap bit;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("error download", "doInBackground: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Log.i("download", "onPostExecute: ");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        Log.i("download", "onProgressUpdate: ");
        imageView.setColorFilter(R.color.imagecolor);
    }
}
```

and onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage();
    downloadImage.execute("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRaL6woz3RgMF-UXU682S_BYb1ayl5xaVancp0PPvF2HnCDmPsb");

    try {
        downloadImage.get();
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to show progressbar where image downloaded and set custom color I do it in onProgressUpdate() but it dosent work

You need to call `publishProgress()` from `doInBackground()`. That will trigger calls to `onProgressUpdate()`. You are not doing this, and so `onProgressUpdate()` will not be called.

> it also shows a white screen until download completed

Remove your `downloadImage.get();` call. That will block the main application thread, and the point of using `AsyncTask` (or its more modern replacements) is to not block the main application thread.

> and if I press back button during the download, it will crash.

If the activity/fragment is destroyed, you should not update the UI. So, you need to confirm in `onPostExecute()` whether it is safe to update the UI (e.g., call `isDestroyed()` on the activity).

Beyond that, [use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with any crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

Comment: thanks for your answer you cover all my question ...it works